# Updating only one cell of a table

Tags: javascript, events, html-table

I created a 3x3 table. Each column is generated using a function. The function basically returns a "td" element. Else where in the code I trigger an event based on some conditions. Whenever the event is triggered, I want to update one particular cell of the table. None of the cells have ids attached to them.
My question is how can I link up the "td" that I want to be updated with the event?

I have no specific context that refers to this td alone.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or some other Javascript toolset? You could use advanced selectors in jQuery like nth-child to path your way to the correct element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle to show you how with jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/HzBFE/

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using any other tools like jQuery my approach might be to find the table which I assume you can do with Javascript. Then for each td element in the table inject a class to them that is unique. You could just give them numbers or something easy. Assuming the numbering never changes you now have an easy way to lookup the td elements later in your code without having to keep a reference to the td element you want.

Instead of adding a class you could just get all the td elements in the table and if you knew the 4th element was always the cell you wanted then you could just keep a reference to that td element.

Answer (score 2):

Without using jQuery or anything, you can use DOM selectors such as .childNodes (and iterating till you're satisfied), .lastChild, .firstChild, .parentNode etc.

[This link](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics) gets you through some examples.

Although, if you are using this a lot, create ID dynamically in JS. Like iterating once through all your table (with .childNodes), assigning an ID (like row1-col2) to every td. It will simplify the rest of your code.